# SignalR and WinRT client: Don't call Wait() on Start()

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, signalr

I have a question regarding SignalR's official documentation - [Hubs API Guide - .NET Client](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client). In the section - **How to establish a connection**. It has been written the following thing:

> The Start method executes asynchronously. To make sure that subsequent
>   lines of code don't execute until after the connection is established,
>   use await in an ASP.NET 4.5 asynchronous method or .Wait() in a
>   synchronous method. Don't use .Wait() in a WinRT client.

Does anyone know what is the specific reason not to call Wait()? Also, does also this apply when I have a WinRT client where I have a call with `hubProxy.Invoke()` to the server?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The reason to not use `Wait` is explained here: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html

Comment: Thank you, Noseratio!
I read the article you shared. I understand why one should not block, i.e. not call Wait() in asynchronous code, but I cannot see how is this related to my question. In the documentation they are saying that I should not block code, i.e. call Wait() in WinRT clients. There is nothing mentioned in relation to asynchronous or synchronous code. Is the code WinRT asynchronous by default or there is something else that I don't know or don't understand?
Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comment:

> There is nothing mentioned in relation to asynchronous or synchronous
>   code. Is the code WinRT asynchronous by default or there is something
>   else that I don't know or don't understand?

In a client-side UI app (including WinRT), there're at least two reason to not block:

- avoid blocking the UI and keeping it fluent;
- avoid the deadlocks as described in [Stephen Cleary's blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html), for cases when there's an `await` in the current chain of calls, on the upper stack frame;

The latter is especially important for WinRT, where asynchrony is pervasive. The whole WinRT framework has been designed to be ["async all the way down"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx), so it's very likely you'd create a deadlock if you use `task.Wait` or `task.Result` anywhere on the UI thread.

For a server-side ASP.NET app, there're also at least two reasons to not block:

- blocking makes your web app less scalable, because the blocked thread could be serving other incoming HTTP requests.
- the same deadlock scenario.

You may want to go through the list of links in [`async-await` wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/async-await/info) for further reading materials.