# SignalR server --> client call not working

Tags: c#, signalr, owin, light-inject

I'm currently using SignalR to communicate between a server and multiple separate processes spawned by the server itself. 
Both Server & Client are coded in C#. I'm using SignalR 2.2.0.0 
On the server side, I use OWIN to run the server. 
I am also using LightInject as an IoC container.

Here is my code:

```
public class AgentManagementStartup
{
    public void ConfigurationOwin(IAppBuilder app, IAgentManagerDataStore dataStore)
    {
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer
        {
            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
            TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple
        };

        var container = new ServiceContainer();
        container.RegisterInstance(dataStore);
        container.RegisterInstance(serializer);
        container.Register<EventHub>();
        container.Register<ManagementHub>();
        var config = container.EnableSignalR();

        app.MapSignalR("", config);
    }
}
```

On the client side, I register this way:

```
public async Task Connect()
{
    try
    {
        m_hubConnection = new HubConnection(m_serverUrl, false);
        m_hubConnection.Closed += OnConnectionClosed;
        m_hubConnection.TraceLevel = TraceLevels.All;
        m_hubConnection.TraceWriter = Console.Out;

        var serializer = m_hubConnection.JsonSerializer;
        serializer.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
        serializer.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;

        m_managementHubProxy = m_hubConnection.CreateHubProxy(AgentConstants.ManagementHub.Name);
        m_managementHubProxy.On("closeRequested", CloseRequestedCallback);

        await m_hubConnection.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        m_logger.Error("Exception encountered in Connect method", e);
    }
}
```

On the server side I send a close request the following way:

```
var managementHub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ManagementHub>();
managementHub.Clients.All.closeRequested();
```

I never receive any callback in `CloseRequestedCallback`. Neither on the Client side nor on the server side I get any errors in the logs.

What did I do wrong here ?

**EDIT 09/10/15**

After some research and modifications, I found out it was linked with the replacement of the IoC container. When I removed everything linked to LightInject and used SignalR as is, everything worked. I was surprised about this since LightInject [documented their integration](http://www.lightinject.net/#signalr) with SignalR.

After I found this, I realised that the `GlobalHost.DependencyResolver` was not the same as the one I was supplying to the `HubConfiguration`. Once I added

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = config.Resolver;
```

before

```
app.MapSignalR("", config);
```

I am now receiving callbacks within `CloseRequestedCallback`. Unfortunately, I get the following error as soon as I call a method from the Client to the Server:

> [Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Infrastructure.SlowCallbackException](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client/Infrastructure/SlowCallbackException.cs)
>
> Possible deadlock detected. A callback registered with "HubProxy.On"
>   or "Connection.Received" has been executing for at least 10 seconds.

I am not sure about the fix I found and what impact it could have on the system. Is it OK to replace the `GlobalHost.DependencyResolver` with my own without registering all of its default content ?

**EDIT 2 09/10/15**

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126624/signalr-autofac-owin-why-doesnt-globalhost-connectionmanager-gethubcontext?rq=1), changing the `GlobalHost.DependencyResolver` is the right thing to do. Still left with no explanation for the `SlowCallbackException` since I do nothing in all my callbacks (yet).

Comment: In relation to your slow callback, perhaps you need to execute that slow process [in the background](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx), and just use SignalR to kick off the task? Anyways, that's a separate issue. Move your IoC solution out of your question and make an answer. Then if necessary, create a new question for your slow callback.

Comment: @mason: I don't have any long running process within any of my callbacks (Client & Server side). That's why I'm surprised to get this error. I understand your point in keeping the question within the same subject, but the issue seems related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Issue 1: IoC Container + Dependency Injection**

If you want to change the IoC for you `HubConfiguration`, you also need to change the one from the `GlobalHost` so that returns the same hub when requesting it ouside of context.

**Issue 2: Unexpected SlowCallbackException**

This exception was caused by the fact that I was using SignalR within a Console Application. The entry point of the app cannot be an `async` method so to be able to call my initial configuration asynchronously I did as follow:

```
private static int Main()
{
    var t = InitAsync();
    t.Wait();
    return t.Result;
}
```

Unfortunately for me, this causes a lot of issues as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835806/signalr-and-winrt-client-dont-call-wait-on-start) & more in details [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html).

By starting my `InitAsync` as follow:

```
private static int Main()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(async ()=> await InitAsync());
    m_waitInitCompletedRequest.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    return (int)EndpointErrorCode.Ended;
}
```

Everything now runs fine and I don't get any deadlocks.

For more details on the issues & answers, you may also refer to the edits in my question.